# Update text with data from a remote .txt file

Tags: php, swift

I am creating a small app for personal use that displays the temperature and humidity from my Arduino weather station. My weather station uploads the temperature and humidity to my web server and saves into a .txt file. I want my app to then pull that data from the server and display in the text areas.

Here is some useful info about how the data is stored on the server:
The humidity and temperature are stored in two different .txt files.
The temperature file - [Temperature](http://torsher.ca/Weather/temperature.txt)
For humidity replace temperature with humidity in the URL

The PHP file used to upload the data -

```
$fileContent = $var1. "%\n";

$fileStatus = file_put_contents('humidity.txt',$fileContent);

if($fileStatus != false)
{
echo "Success: Values written to server";
}

else
{
echo "Fail: Values were written to server";
}
?>
```

The humidity PHP file is the same except for the names and file URL.

Finally here is my ViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var tempLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var humidLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var refreshButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    var urlString = "http://torsher.ca/Weather/temperature.txt"

    var url = NSURL(string: urlString)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in

        var urlContent = (NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))

        var contentArray = urlContent!.componentsSeparatedByString("<span class=\"phrase\">")

        var newContentArray = contentArray[1].componentsSeparatedByString("</span>")

        var tempContent = newContentArray[0] as String

        println(tempContent)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.tempLabel.text = tempContent
        }

    }

    task.resume()
    }


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
```

I want to be able to force refresh and refresh when the app opens. My Arduino pushes new data every 15 minutes. But for creation I am manually updating the .txt file by using the URL for each reading. Feel free to update the readings if need be to test.

Put the value you want right after the '=' sign in the URL.
[Temperature.php](http://torsher.ca/Weather/temperature.php?temp=000)
For Humidity replace temperature and temp with humidity and humid.

Thanks!

Comment: Sidenote: Why is there a `%` sign in `"%\n";`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I assume because he wants to write the humidy to the file as [number]%.

Comment: @DigitalChris I kind of thought that after. I edited my comment and removed the "it shouldn't be in there". You stand at being correct though.

Answer (score 0):

If you change

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
```

with

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 15.0)){(data, response, error) in
```

You can set the `NSURLRequestCachePolicy`, `ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData` should (as it states) ignore all caches and just request the page without looking at any caches.

This will also include a timeout in the request

Your app will also contain this function in its `appDelegate` you could call a function in which you reload the data in here, this will get executed when you open (or from the multitask screen) the app

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}
```

EDIT:

Playground:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import XCPlayground


var urlString = "http://torsher.ca/Weather/temperature.txt"
var url = NSURL(string: urlString)

func getData(){
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 15.0)){(data, response, error) in
        var urlContent = (NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        var tempContent:String = urlContent as! String    
        println(tempContent)
    }

    task.resume()
} 

getData()

XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()
```

Comment: ok. I can now see the console display the value from the server (20) but now it is saying my array is out of range.  This array as above. (urlContent!.componentsSeparatedByString("<span class=\"phrase\">"))

Comment: ok. I can now see the console display the value from the server (20) but now it is saying my array is out of range. This array as above. (urlContent!.componentsSeparatedByString("<span class=\"phrase\">")

Comment: I’ve edited the answer and put in the Playground file I used to answer your question. I use swift 1.2 with the newest xCode Beta so this should also work for you if you use the same versions

Comment: I am sorry to bother you like this, but you seem to know what you're talking about. I was able to get the code to work in a playground as well but as soon as I tried it in my regular code it did not work. The difference is the "XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()" line, with out it the values are not printed in the console. have any ideas to get it to work in the ViewController and not just the playground?

Comment: For use in the view controller you should remove the import XCPlayground and XCSet.....(), these are merely to make sure playground supports asynchronous request, you should be able to paste the rest accordignly